# How to find a numeric value in a string

Tags: vb.net, artificial-intelligence, information-retrieval, information-extraction

I am attempting to create a method which analyzes a string of text to see if it contains a numeric value.  For instance, given the following string:

> What is 2 * 2?

I need to determine the following information:

- The string contains a numeric value: `True`
- What is the numeric value that it contains: `2` (anyone of them should make the function return true and I should put the position of each of the 2's in the string in a variable such as position 0 for the first 2)

Here is the code I have so far:

```
Public Function InQuestion(question As String) As Boolean
    ' Possible substring operations using the position of the number in the string?
End Function
```

Comment: If you have multiple questions, you should ask them in separate posts.  Please make your questions more specific.  For instance, with question #1, are you simply asking how to search a string to see if it contains a numeric value?  If so, it would be better to ask something like that, specifically, without all the background details that aren't really related to your question.  Also, show what you have tried and explain how it is that it's not working.

Comment: steven I fixed the question if you marked me down please undo it or tell me whats wrong with the question.

Comment: oh numeric is only numbers in integer, decimal,double format for specifics. Can not hold numbers higher then possible by an integer, decimal, and double formats. But I will go with integer or decimal for ease of answering.

Comment: I've edited your question to give you an idea of what I mean.  Please modify it if I got anything wrong (such as the desired output).  I removed my down vote.

Comment: thanks steven yes that is more precise.

Comment: Was I correct, that given that input, you need to get the value `2`?  Or did you need the whole expression `2 * 2`?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. Again these are all weird questions and so I might explain the question in the first edit and change it later if I am having a difficult time explaining it or it is too distracting. If you think I should use an open source API for something like this you can suggest one although their is some features I want to code in myself.

Comment: Yes that's correct steven the first edit please change to first edit.

Comment: Getting the mathematical expression from the string and then solving that expression are two entirely different tasks.  I'd worry about solving the first one before trying to tackle the second.  I know very little about AI, so unfortunately, I can't help you further.  If you could develop some simple rules, you could possibly use RegEx to pull out the expression, but beyond that, you'd be essentially dealing with natural-language processing which is a far more complicated proposition.

Comment: I meant I need to pull both 2 in the above post. I just added information telling people I need to keep the position or index of each number but other then that I can convert easily the string to an integer by correct casting or CInt(string). Example: 2 * 2  I need to get both 2's but I need their position to substring to the number and solve the problem. I will worry about algebra type expressions later though but good thought on the matter.

Comment: whats wrong with my question? I edited it and it should be clear  enough to answer. This is absurd.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/24842/discussion-between-jeffery-and-steven-doggart)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example console application:

```
Module Module1
    Sub Main()
        Dim results As List(Of NumericValue) = GetNumericValues("What is 2 * 2?")
        For Each i As NumericValue In results
            Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", i.Position, i.Value)
        Next
        Console.ReadKey()
    End Sub

    Public Class NumericValue
        Public Sub New(value As Decimal, position As Integer)
            Me.Value = value
            Me.Position = position
        End Sub

        Public Property Value As Decimal
        Public Property Position As Integer
    End Class

    Public Function GetNumericValues(data As String) As List(Of NumericValue)
        Dim values As New List(Of NumericValue)()
        Dim wordDelimiters() As Char = New Char() {" "c, "*"c, "?"c}
        Dim position As Integer = 0
        For Each word As String In data.Split(wordDelimiters, StringSplitOptions.None)
            Dim value As Decimal
            If Decimal.TryParse(word, value) Then
                values.Add(New NumericValue(value, position))
            End If
            position += word.Length + 1
        Next
        Return values
    End Function
End Module
```

As you can see, it passes the string `"What is 2 * 2?" and it outputs the positions and values of each numeric value:

> 8: 2
>
> 12: 2

Comment: thanks steven. I have the place to try your code the way you wrote it and marked up 1 because the answer was helpful.

Comment: it works thanks! Maybe I can use some built in functions in visual studio to answer algebra functions.

Comment: I added some code with regex in a revision to add in simple operators such as *,/,+,and - for figuring out simple math questions and it works! I might have to do something different for algebra or mixed type cases such as:  what is 2*2 + 2?